# elasticsearch autocomplete suggested completion on multiple fields and for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, autosuggest, search-suggestion

So we have 2 cases:

1. A single search input on the homepage
2. A orderform with multiple input fields

   [Resultitems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wswoA.png)
   [Homepage single searchfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww6vl.png)
   [Orderingform multiple search fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44nJc.png)

So in summary:

1. On our site users search for companies, select one, and order it.
2. We want to make a global search field, for on homepage. And we have a order form, where we have 4 input fields; company name, company number, company address (most often street), company city.
3. Aggregations on city, legal_form, and federal_state, which users can use as filters
4. general idea is: user lands on home or ordering form page, perform search, filter, then find the company, click company result -> this loads company details in ordering form so user can order.

Question:

1. I'm confused how autocomplete could work on single global search field and a ordering form that has 4 (or 5) fields
2. could you help with example queries we could use for our scenario?

Things we've done:

1. copy fields to generic fields so we can query a single field (e.g. street, zip, city are merged in 1 full_address field)
2. created a custom analyser for German streetnames and phonetic

Things for advice: Homepage search

1. single searchfield should search all_names, all_address, company_number, all_offices (= all cities) and return highest relevant
2. highest relevant can partially be achieved by tuning "weight" and "boost" in the query
3. however I don't understand how the "search-as-you-type" completion would work, when user is entering in 1 search field different terms (like as example name + zipcode + city)
4. Would the autocomplete work on only the first 3 letters? Please explain.

Things for advice: orderform search

1. the orderform has 4 fields; company name, company number, address, city
2. ideally, when user is typing, he should get autocompletions on the fields he is typing
3. this is simple; name field = name suggestions, etc.
4. when multiple fields are filled, should the autocompletions only be suggestions matching all entered fields? like part of company name is filled, then address auto-completes are only from matched company names? should we want this?
5. should we add a 5th global search field like on the homepage to the ordering form?

Example analyzer and mappings:

```
    {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
            },
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "german_stop": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords":  "_german_" 
                    },
                    "german_stemmer": {
                    "type":       "stemmer",
                    "language":   "light_german"
                    },
                    "snowball": {
                        "type": "snowball",
                        "language": "German2"
                    },
                    "german_phonetic": {
                        "type": "phonetic",
                        "encoder": "koelnerphonetik",
                        "replace": false
                    },
                    "address_synonyms": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "synonyms": [ "str, strasse, straße => strass" ]
                    }
                },      
                "analyzer": {
                    "names_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "char_filter": [
                            "html_strip"
                          ],
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "word_delimiter",
                            "german_normalization",
                            "german_phonetic",
                            "asciifolding",
                            "apostrophe"
                        ]
                    },
                    
                    "address_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "german_normalization",
                            "german_stop",
                            "snowball",
                            "german_stemmer",
                            "address_synonyms",
                            "german_phonetic",
                            "asciifolding",
                            "apostrophe",
                            "word_delimiter"
                        ]
                    },
    
                    "keyword_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "german_normalization",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
    
                "all_names":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer": "names_analyzer",
                    "fields":{
                        "search-as-you-type":{
                        "type":"search_as_you_type"
                        }
                    }
                },
    
                "name":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer": "names_analyzer",
                    "copy_to": "all_names"
                },
        
                "alt_names":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "include_in_root": true, 
                    "properties":{
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "names_analyzer",
                            "copy_to": "all_names"                  },
                        "office":{
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "copy_to": "all_offices",
                            "fields":{
                                "text":{
                                    "type":"text"
                                },
                                "keyword_analyzed":{
                                    "type":"text",
                                    "analyzer":"keyword_analyzer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "branches":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "include_in_root": true, 
                    "properties":{
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "names_analyzer",
                            "copy_to": "all_names"
                        },
                        "office":{
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "copy_to": "all_offices",
                            "fields":{
                                "text":{
                                    "type":"text"
                                },
                                "keyword_analyzed":{
                                    "type":"text",
                                    "analyzer":"keyword_analyzer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
        
                "full_address":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer": "address_analyzer",
                    "fields":{
                       "search-as-you-type":{
                          "type":"search_as_you_type"
                       }
                    }
                 },
    
                 "all_address":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer": "address_analyzer",
                    "fields":{
                       "search-as-you-type":{
                          "type":"search_as_you_type"
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "street":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer": "address_analyzer",
                    "copy_to": "all_address",
                    "fields":{
                        "search-as-you-type":{
                            "type":"search_as_you_type"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "zipcode":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "copy_to": "all_address",
                    "fields":{
                        "search-as-you-type":{
                            "type":"search_as_you_type"
                        },
                        "text": {
                            "type":"text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "city":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "copy_to": [ "all_offices", "all_address" ],
                    "fields":{
                        "search-as-you-type":{
                            "type":"search_as_you_type"
                        },
                        "text":{
                            "type":"text",
                            "analyzer": "address_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                 },
    
                 "legal_form":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "fields":{
                       "search-as-you-type":{
                          "type":"search_as_you_type"
                       },
                       "text":{
                        "type":"text"
                    }
                    }
                 },
    
                 "all_offices":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "fields":{
                       "search-as-you-type":{
                          "type":"search_as_you_type"
                       },
                       "text":{
                        "type":"text"
                    }
                    }
                 },
    
                 "office":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "copy_to": "all_offices"
                 },
        
                 "registrar":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "copy_to": "all_offices"
                 },
        
                 "former_registrar":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "copy_to": "all_offices"
                 },
        
                 "state":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "fields":{
                       "text":{
                        "type":"text"
                        }
                    }
                 },
        
                 "company_number":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "fields":{
                       "search-as-you-type":{
                          "type":"search_as_you_type"
                       },
                       "text":{
                        "type":"text"
                        }
                    }
                 },
        
                 "status":{
                    "type":"keyword",
                    "fields":{
                       "text":{
                        "type":"text"
                        }
                    }
                 }
    
            
            }
          }
    
    }
```

Example global search query:

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": { 
                "should": [
                    { 
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Hans-Sachs-Straße",
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                        "minimum_should_match": "60%"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": [ 
                    { "term":  { "state": "" }},
                    { "term":  { "all_offices": "" }}
                ]
            }
        },
        "highlight": {
            "fields": {
                "name": {},
                "full_address": {},
                "office": {},
                "company_number": {},
                "registrar": {},
                "native_company_number": {}
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "states": {
            "terms": { "field": "state" }
            },
            "city": {
            "terms": { "field": "all_offices" }
            }
      }
      }
```

Example orderform query:

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": { 
                "should": [               
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "str",
                            "minimum_should_match": "60%",
                            "boost": 2,
                            "fields": [
                            "full_address.search-as-you-type",
                            "full_address.search-as-you-type._2gram",
                            "full_address.search-as-you-type._3gram"
                            ]
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "HR",
                            "minimum_should_match": "60%",
                            "boost": 5,
                            "fields": [
                            "company_number.search-as-you-type",
                            "company_number.search-as-you-type._2gram",
                            "company_number.search-as-you-type._3gram"
                            ]
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "DK",
                            "minimum_should_match": "60%",
                            "boost": 5,
                            "fields": [
                            "all_names.search-as-you-type",
                            "all_names.search-as-you-type._2gram",
                            "all_names.search-as-you-type._3gram"
                            ]
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "Dus",
                            "minimum_should_match": "60%",
                            "boost": 3,
                            "fields": [
                            "all_offices.search-as-you-type",
                            "all_offices.search-as-you-type._2gram",
                            "all_offices.search-as-you-type._3gram"
                            ]
                            }
                    }                                                   
                ]
            },
            "filter": [ 
                { "term":  { "state": "" }},
                { "term":  { "all_offices": "" }}
            ]
        },
        "highlight": {
            "fields": {
                "name": {},
                "full_address": {},
                "office": {},
                "company_number": {},
                "registrar": {},
                "native_company_number": {}
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "states": {
            "terms": { "field": "state" }
            },
            "city": {
            "terms": { "field": "all_offices" }
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I can't help with the autocomplete on 4 fields because I'm working on something similar (how I found your page). However, for the autocomplete for one field, you should create a custom analyzer (lets call it 'autocomplete') and make sure that the field that you are searching has the 'autocomplete' analyzer as its analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how autocomplete can work for multiple fields, with different `fields` dataType.

I have enabled `analyzers` and `search_analyzers` as well on these fields so I am taking advantage of substring (`n-gram tokenziers` based) search.

`_settings` to create index:

```
PUT /yourIndexName
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 15,
    "index.default_pipeline": "your_pipeline - if any else remove this",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        },
        "standardTokenizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`_mappings` for your index:

```
PUT /yourIndexName/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "yourFieldName0": { //or yourObject.yourFieldName
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "suggest": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type"
        },
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "yourFieldName1": { //this is a simple string
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "standard",      
      "fields": {
        "suggest": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type"
        }
      }
    },
    "yourFieldName2": { //this is an array of strings.
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "standardTokenizer",
      "search_analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": {
        "suggest": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type"
        }
      }
    },
    "locations": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    },
    "yourFieldName3": { //array of strings. it is used for facets.
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you insert your data in the index. Now, let's cover `search-ui`: https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/tutorials/elasticsearch

```
const config = {
  searchQuery: {
    search_fields: {
      "yourFieldName0.suggest": { weight: 3, snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false }},
      "yourFieldName1.suggest": {snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false }},
      "yourFieldName2.suggest": {snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false }}
    },
    result_fields: {
      resultsPerPage: 5,
      _id: {}, name: {}, yourFieldName0: { snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false } }
    },
    disjunctiveFacets: ["yourFieldName0.suggest"],
    facets: {
      "yourFieldName0.keyword": { type: "value" },
      "yourFieldName3.keyword": { type: "value" },
      locations: {
        center: "42.0001, -73.0005",
        type: "range",
        unit: "km",
        ranges: [
          { from: 0, to: 5, name: "With in 5 Km" },
          { from: 0, to: 20, name: "With in 20 Km" },
          { from: 0, to: 150, name: "With in 150 Km" },
        ],
      }
    }
  },
  autocompleteQuery: {
    results: { //this is how you can enable autocomplete on multiple fields.
      search_fields: {
        "yourFieldName0.suggest": { weight: 3, snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false } },
        "yourFieldName0": { weight: 3, snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false } },
        "yourFieldName1.suggest": {snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false }},
        "yourFieldName1": {snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false }},
      },
      result_fields: {
        _id: {}, yourFieldName0: { snippet: { size: 50, fallback: false } }
      }
    }
  },
  apiConnector: connector,
  alwaysSearchOnInitialLoad: true,
  initialState: {
    resultsPerPage: 10,
    sortList: [ { field: "_score", direction:"desc" }, { field: "yourFieldName0", direction:"asc" } ]
  }
};
```